# Cumulative sum in Python without the current row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I need to find the cumulative sum of the 3 previous rows without calculate the current one, here a short example:

| ID | SUM |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 3 |

That's the result I want to reach:

| ID | SUM |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| B | 0 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 9 |
| B | 10 |
| C | 0 |
| C | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby.apply` with `shift` and `rolling`

```
df['SUM'] = df.groupby('ID')['SUM'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=0)
                                                     .rolling(3,min_periods=1).sum())

Out[50]:
  ID   SUM
0  A   0.0
1  B   0.0
2  B   5.0
3  B   9.0
4  B  10.0
5  C   0.0
6  C   1.0
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!! That's working for me:)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df['SUM'] = (df.groupby('ID')['SUM']
               .transform(lambda x: x.rolling(4,min_periods=1).sum())
               .sub(df['SUM'])
            )
```

Output:

```
  ID  SUM
0  A    0
1  B    0
2  B    5
3  B    9
4  B   10
5  C    0
6  C    1
```